# Netbeans fails to run php code with WAMP

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, wamp, netbeans-8

I have installed netbeans IDE 8.2 on Windows 10 and I am trying to run a php project with wamp.

I am storing the project on wamp/www directory, however when I am running the index.php file there is an error page can't load.

Any suggestions? Maybe are the ports of the apache?

[image]

Comment: post your error log/screenshot

Comment: You probably have not setup NetBeans correctly! Are you trying to use the internal browser or a external one? It works fine for me including XDEBUG

Comment: @RiggsFolly what do you mean internal or external browser?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, means an internal browser which is inside the NetBeans itself. If you are using that browser your output will be displayed inside the NetBeans rather than external browsers like Chrome or Firefox. You need to post error log or screenshot of your output for the better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Before running your project make sure that Wamp server is running along with Apache. Usually, Apache runs under port number 80, if you configured Apache port to other port like 8080 you should use http://localhost:8080/test/index.php in your browser URL.